Optimizing MorphMany Relationship with Eager Loading - Accessing Parent Model Data In Laravel 11
We're using Laravel 11 with a morphMany relationship in our application (PHP 8.2, MySQL). Here's a simplified example of the code:
// Post.php
class Post extends BaseModel
{
  public function blocks(): MorphMany
  {
    return $this->morphMany(Block::class, 'blockable');
  }
}

// Block.php
class Block extends Model
{
  public function blockable(): MorphTo
  {
    return $this->morphTo();
  }

  public function alt(): string
  {
    $alt = '';

    if ($this->caption) {
      $alt = $this->caption;
    } else if ($this->blockable->title) {
      $alt = 'Block from ' . $this->blockable->title;
    }

    return $alt;
  }
}

// PostController.php
$posts = Post::where('status_id', 1)
  ->with('blocks')
  ->get();

// This generates ~59 statements (many duplicates)

$posts = Post::where('status_id', 1)
  ->with('blocks', 'blocks.blockable')
  ->get();

// This generates ~17 statements (better, but extra queries)

$posts = Post::where('status_id', 1)
  ->with('blocks')
  ->get();

public function alt(Post $blockable): string // Pass parent as argument
{
  $alt = '';

  if ($this->caption) {
      $alt = $this->caption;
  } else if ($blockable->title) {
      $alt = 'Block from ' . $blockable->title;
  }

  return $alt;
}

// This generates ~14 statements (feels like bad design)

Is there a better way to access the parent model data within Block::alt() without additional queries or passing the parent explicitly? or is this the most optimal solution?

I don't know how you're getting 17 statements with a query that looks like it only needs 3. In my opinion, the logic just isn't big enough to warrant a method like that.
// 2 statements.
// select * from posts where status_id = 1
// select * from blocks where blockable_type = App\\Models\\Post and blockable_id IN (...)
$posts = Post::where('status_id', 1)
  ->with('blocks')
  ->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    foreach ($post->blocks as $block) {
        echo $block->caption
            ? ($post->title ? "Block from {$post->title}" : '')
            : '';
    }
}


class Post extends Model
{
    public function alt(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::get(
            fn () => $this->title
                ? "Block from {$this->title}"
                : ''
        );
    }
}

class Blockable extends Model
{
    public function alt(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::get(
            fn () => $this->caption ?? $this->blockable->alt
        );
    }
}


Yeah, you're right 17 statements include other functionality on the page. The above is correct, and matches what we accomplished with our method. The only feeling here is that $block->alt() feels understandable, repeatable code. Your solution will need to be repeated every time we list blocks which is in multiple places. Ideally, I think we need a solution which is $block->alt() and not $block->alt($post), or your solution above. It feels like it should be possible somehow.

How about this: Implement an accessor in the Post model (and every model that could be returned by Block's blockable method as well as Block. I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean
